# fread showing an error

Tags: php, fread

```
<?php 
$email=$_GET['email'];
$file=fread(fopen("user/".$email.".txt",'r'),filesize("user/". $email.".txt"));
? >
```

This shows the error

> Warning: fread(): Length parameter must be greater than 0

Comment: that means either file not exist or file have nothing in it or  may be file permission issue. check file permission (need to be 644)

Comment: Attempting all the calls in one line may look 'neat' but it doesn't allow for any error checking/validation.  You don't even check if the file exists before assuming it's there, readable and has content.

Comment: `<?php
error_repoerting(E_ALL); 
ini_set('display_errors',1);
$email=$_GET['email'];
$file=fread(fopen("user/".$email.".txt",'r'),filesize("user/". $email.".txt"));
? >`  try this

Comment: Are you trying to store the contents of the file in `$file`?